# How to create a content blocker for ios?

Tags: ios, swift, mobile-safari, safari-content-blocker

Pre-requisites:
Xcode: 14
iOS: 16
Device: iPhone 14

Trying to create a simple content blocker using the **content blocker extension** from the **Xcode**.
Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a simple Xcode Project.
2. Add a new target -> Content blocker extension
3. Give a name to the target.

You will see 2 files:

1. ContentBlockerRequestHandler.swift
2. blockerList.json

What I'm trying is adding a site in blockerList.json file:

```
{
    "action": {
        "type": "block"
    },
    "trigger": {
        "url-filter": "www.google.com"
    }
}
```

After running the same in iPhone 14 it's not blocking google.com.

P.S: Content blocker is enabled in the safari settings and extensions are toggled on in safari extension part.

Comment: google.com is different from www.google.com .

Comment: actually i'm using ".*google.*", just for reference I've given google.com

Comment: Did you try : ".*\.google\..*" : filter are like regular expressions not unix file search patterns.